# Speed-Dial Icons not centered

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I am trying to build a Speed Dial for a web app, but no matter what I try, the Icons in the Speed Dial are off-center.

I followed the tutorial on https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/floating-action-buttons, but even if I copy&paste the code from there, The Icons are not centered

```
<v-speed-dial
        fab
        bottom
        right
        fixed
        v-model="fab"
        direction="top"
        transition="slide-y-reverse-transition"
      >
        <v-btn
          icon
          slot="activator"
          fab
          dark
          color="blue lighten-2"
          v-model="fab"
        >
          <v-icon>account_circle</v-icon>

          <v-icon>close</v-icon>
        </v-btn>

        <v-btn fab dark small color="green">
          <v-icon>edit</v-icon>
        </v-btn>

        <v-btn fab dark small color="indigo">
          <v-icon>add</v-icon>
        </v-btn>
      </v-speed-dial>
```

**Actual Behavior:**

[image: Actual Behavior (1)] [image: Actual Behavior (2)]

**Expected Behavior:**

[image: Expected Behavior (1)] [image: Expected Behavior (2)]

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong there?

Answer (score 1):

You may want to check your v-icon align properties in the console.  This css seems to affect the position of the interior icon.

```
.v-icon {
    align-items: center;
    display: inline-flex;
    -webkit-font-feature-settings: "liga";
    font-feature-settings: "liga";
    font-size: 24px;
    justify-content: center;
    line-height: 1;
    transition: .3s cubic-bezier(.25,.8,.5,1);
    vertical-align: text-bottom;
    box-shadow: 0 0 black;
}
```